# I want to write a macro to type a series of keystrokes before i send out an email

Tags: vba, email, outlook, keystroke

I currently have a .oft template that i use when sending an email to a customer with a quote attached.  It includes some highlights of the quote.
For example number of days, etc.  What am i currently doing manually is typing the following keystrokes CTRL+A, ALT, O, I, N, ALT, P, PC, N.  Which basically turns off highlighting for the whole document and removes the watermark.  The watermark is a textual visual reminder to make sure the quote is attached as well as another document.

Can anyone get me started on a macro for this?

I haven't' tried anything yet as i don't know where to start.  What i am trying to accomplish is for all highlighting to go away, as well as the watermark.  Both of these are used as visual reminders to check an often-changing part of the email or add an attachment.

Comment: Isn't there a macro recorder that allows you to record the key strokes?

Comment: No, not in Outlook.

Comment: Outlook has never had a macro recorder. You need to learn the basics of VBA first.

Comment: Your question is more suited to a forum not a Q & A. Search term is `SendKeys`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the `ItemSend` event of the Outlook `Application` class to handle outgoing emails in Outlook, for example:

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)  
 Dim prompt As String  
 prompt = "Are you sure you want to send " & Item.Subject & "?"  
 If MsgBox(prompt, vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Sample") = vbNo Then  
   Cancel = True  
 End If  
End Sub
```

See [Getting started with VBA in Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/library-reference/concepts/getting-started-with-vba-in-office) as a starting point.

Also you may find the article I wrote for the technical blog a decade ago helpful - [How To: Change an Outlook e-mail message before sending using C# or VB.NET](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/outlook-change-message-before-sending/).

Comment: This doesn't give a novice like me much to go on?  And I'm not sure your suggestion above, allows me to key in keystrokes?

Comment: As I recommended, start from [Getting started with VBA in Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/library-reference/concepts/getting-started-with-vba-in-office).